# Regression with unary plus

Tags: awk, string, gawk

Previously, numeric conversions could be triggered by either adding zero (+0),
unary plus (+) or unary minus (-):

```
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print "01" + 0}'
1

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print +"01"}'
1

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print -"01"}'
-1
```

However, now conversion only happens with adding zero and unary minus:

```
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.2.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 3.1.6-p1, GNU MP 6.1.2)

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print "01" + 0}'
1

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print +"01"}'
01

$ gawk 'BEGIN {print -"01"}'
-1
```

Does anyone know where this change was mentioned or why it was done?

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

Comment: FWIW, the awk maintained by Brian Kernighan had that issue where `+` was a no-op and would not cause conversion to numerical (that's why I recommend to use `x+0` here for portability even if `+ x` should work as per POSIX). I did report it to bwk some time ago. It does look like the new behaviour in gawk is not intentional. A comment in the code says `// Force argument to be numeric` followed by something that doesn't do it. You may want to report it.

Comment: [Source code](https://fossies.org/diffs/gawk/4.1.4_vs_4.2.0/interpret.h-diff.html) search for 'case Op_unary_plus:'

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas fixed now http://github.com/onetrueawk/awk/commit/32093f5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is certainly unintentional.  We (the [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) maintainers) will look to fix it.

In the future, it would help, A LOT, if such questions were sent to the gawk bug reporting address (`bug-gawk@gnu.org`, see `gawk --help`), so that the developers would learn about these issues and fix them.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens As Arnold says, it was unintentional. Unintentional changes can hardly be mentioned in release notes etc. I'm assuming it may be mentioned as a bug fix in the future though, if the authors feel that it's a significant enough bug.

Comment: It's tricky to decide whether to send something to the bug-reporting address when you genuinely suspect it might be an intentional change.  You could argue that in that case it represents a bug in the documentation, but it's natural to want to minimise the time developers spend triaging non-bugs.